# Reductions under lambda in dependently typed lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

I am currently reading a Simon Thompson's Type Theory book. In chapter 5 he introduces a system TT(0,C), which limits a notion of reduction . In this notion of reduction, reductions under lambda are forbidden. Why is it useful? Will we lose strong normalization property if we allow reductions under lambda?